# Sending text to external program's textbox

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand or find out how to send text via a button click to a external program setup.

Like for example say I'm installing an app I go through the process of a app and it asks me to put in a serial or product key. I want to make a program where I can store the right serial number in and when im at that window hit a button and it will send the serial to the textbox of the installer.

It's not for pirating or anything like that. I wanted to make a program so when I format I don't have to go through tons of paper work to find all me codes I want to store it all in a program and then in the install process just go through and have my program put the right codes in at the right time.

I have been looking up find window, find windowex and send message tutorials but did not understand fully how to achieve this.

Like I know how to get a window but I'm not sure how to find the right textbox or how to send anything to it if I find the right one if that makes sense. I'm sorry I have dyslexia so have a little trouble explaining.

Comment: if this is just a utility for you to use and you don't really care about coding it yourself, [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) will do this for you.

Comment: use UIAutomation to find other app window's textbox and enter the text you have.